# Prove if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable function (finite in almost every point) and we have..

Tags: measure-theory

Prove if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable function (finite in almost every point) and we have $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, and $f_n\rightarrow g$ in measure then $f=g$ almost in every point.

**My attempt:**

Let $\epsilon ,\delta >0$.

As $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure then exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N_1$ then $m\{x:|fn(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon/2\}<\delta$

Moreover, as $f_n\rightarrow g$ in measure then exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N_2$ then: $m\{x:|f_n(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon/2\}<\delta$

Let $N=min\{N_1 ,N_2\}$, if $n>N$ then

$m\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon\}<\delta$

As $\delta$ is arbitrary then $m\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon\}=0$ and this implies f=g in almost every point.

Is correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct,since

$$\{|f-g|>\epsilon\} \subseteq \{|f_n-g| > \epsilon/2\} \cup \{|f_n-f| > \epsilon/2\}$$